# SQL Server check case-sensitivity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-sensitive

How can I check to see if a database in SQL Server is case-sensitive? I have previously been running the query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' = 'a' THEN 'NOT CASE SENSITIVE' ELSE 'CASE SENSITIVE' END
```

But I am looking for other ways as this has actually given me issues in the past.

Edit - A little more info:
An existing product has many pre-written stored procedures. In a stored procedure `@test != @TEST` depending on the sensitivity of the server itself. So what I'm looking for is the best way to check the server for its sensitivity.

Comment: When in doubt, drive both sides of the comparison to uppercase with UPPER...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Collation can be set at various levels:

1. Server
2. Database
3. Column

So you could have a Case Sensitive Column in a Case Insensitive database.  I have not yet come across a situation where a business case could be made for case sensitivity of a single column of data, but I suppose there could be.

**Check Server Collation**

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')
```

**Check Database Collation**

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('AdventureWorks', 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

**Check Column Collation**

```
select table_name, column_name, collation_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = @table_name
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you can set the collation also in SQL using `SELECT * FROM foo where x = 'y' COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as`

Comment: Just adding one more piece to the puzzle: if the collation name contains _CI_ it's case-insensitive, if it contains _CS_ it's case-sensitive.
[Read more in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx)

Comment: There are many things there are case sensitive, like URLs, passwords so there you go, examples of case sensitive columns.

Comment: @Gordon I hope you're not storing passwords in plaintext in your database!

Comment: @gdoron: I've yet to see a case sensitive URL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996919/should-url-be-case-sensitive . Sure, the get part can be, but not the domain.

Comment: @JeffMeden 3 years later I just saw your comment.
No, I'm not storing passwords as plain text, anyway, hashed passwords are case sensitive.

Comment: @MitchWheat we just had a big bug in my company because Google changed one of its websites to be case sensitive. They are real and they are spectacular.

Comment: @gdoron: you are saying that google changed the domain part of a URL to be case sensitive? What's the URL?

Comment: @MitchWheat, no, where did you see my writing about the domain? I wrote URLs, domains are case insensitive. paths and querystrings on the other hand aren't.

Comment: @gdoron which is what my comment states above! -> "Sure, the get part can be, but not the domain."

Answer (score 37):

If you installed SQL Server with the default collation options, you might find that the following queries return the same results:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( 
    mycolumn VARCHAR(10) 
) 
GO 

SET NOCOUNT ON 

INSERT mytable VALUES('Case') 
GO 

SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='Case' 
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='caSE' 
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='case'
```

You can alter your query by forcing collation at the column level:

```
SELECT myColumn FROM myTable  
    WHERE myColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'caSE' 

SELECT myColumn FROM myTable  
    WHERE myColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'case' 

SELECT myColumn FROM myTable  
    WHERE myColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'Case' 

-- if myColumn has an index, you will likely benefit by adding 
-- AND myColumn = 'case' 

SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('<database name>', 'Collation')
```

As changing this setting can impact applications and SQL queries, I would isolate this test first. From SQL Server 2000, you can easily run an ALTER TABLE statement to change the sort order of a specific column, forcing it to be case sensitive. First, execute the following query to determine what you need to change it back to:

```
EXEC sp_help 'mytable'
```

The second recordset should contain the following information, in a default scenario:

Column_Name Collation

---

mycolumn    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Whatever the 'Collation' column returns, you now know what you need to change it back to after you make the following change, which will force case sensitivity:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
    ALTER COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR(10) 
    COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS 
GO 



SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='Case' 
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='caSE' 
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='case'
```

If this screws things up, you can change it back, simply by issuing a new ALTER TABLE statement (be sure to replace my COLLATE identifier with the one you found previously):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
    ALTER COLUMN mycolumn VARCHAR(10) 
    COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

If you are stuck with SQL Server 7.0, you can try this workaround, which might be a little more of a performance hit (you should only get a result for the FIRST match):

```
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE 
    mycolumn = 'case' AND 
    CAST(mycolumn AS VARBINARY(10)) = CAST('Case' AS VARBINARY(10)) 

SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE 
    mycolumn = 'case' AND 
    CAST(mycolumn AS VARBINARY(10)) = CAST('caSE' AS VARBINARY(10)) 

SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE 
    mycolumn = 'case' AND 
    CAST(mycolumn AS VARBINARY(10)) = CAST('case' AS VARBINARY(10)) 

-- if myColumn has an index, you will likely benefit by adding 
-- AND myColumn = 'case'
```

Answer (score 13):

SQL server determines case sensitivity by `COLLATION`.

`COLLATION` can be set at various levels.

1. Server-level
2. Database-level
3. Column-level
4. Expression-level

[Here is the MSDN reference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx)

One can check the `COLLATION` at each level as mentioned in [Raj More's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411260/1184435).

**Check Server Collation**

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')
```

**Check Database Collation**

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('AdventureWorks', 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

**Check Column Collation**

```
select table_name, column_name, collation_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = @table_name
```

**Check Expression Collation**

For expression level `COLLATION` you need to look at the expression. :)

It would be generally at the end of the expression as in below example.

```
SELECT name FROM customer ORDER BY name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI;
```

**Collation Description**

For getting description of each `COLLATION` value try this.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_helpcollations()
```

And you should see something like this.

[image]

You can always put a `WHERE` clause to filter and see description only for your `COLLATION`.

You can find a list of collations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174596(v=sql.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You're interested in the collation. You could build something based on this snippet:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'Collation');
```

---

**Update**
Based on your edit — If `@test` and `@TEST` can ever refer to two different variables, it's not SQL Server.  If you see problems where the *same* variable is not equal to itself, check if that variable is `NULL`, because `NULL = NULL` returns `false.

Comment: `NULL = NULL` test would be dependant on ANSI_NULLS isn't it? `where NULL IS NULL` would return true (Handling NULL Values in MSSQL Queries)[http://www.peter-urda.com/2010/11/handling-null-values-in-mssql-queries]

Answer (score 2):

The best way to work with already created tables is that,
Go to Sql Server Query Editor

Type: `sp_help <tablename>`

This will show table's structure , see the details for the desired field under COLLATE column.

then type in the query like :

```
SELECT myColumn FROM myTable  
WHERE myColumn COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = 'Case'
```

It could be different character schema <`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`>, so better to find out the exact schema that has been used against that column.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check to see if a database in SQL Server is case-sensitive?

You can use below query that returns your informed database is case sensitive or not or is in binary sort(with null result):

```
;WITH collations AS (
    SELECT 
        name,
        CASE 
            WHEN description like '%case-insensitive%' THEN 0 
            WHEN description like '%case-sensitive%' THEN 1 
        END isCaseSensitive
    FROM 
        sys.fn_helpcollations()
)
SELECT *
FROM collations
WHERE name = CONVERT(varchar, DATABASEPROPERTYEX('yourDatabaseName','collation'));
```

For more read [this MSDN information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230914.aspx) ;).

Answer (score -3):

SQL Server is not case sensitive. `SELECT * FROM SomeTable` is the same as `SeLeCT * frOM soMetaBLe`.

Comment: That's not what he's talking about.  He means how _data_ is compared, not how code is processed.

Comment: I think the question is about comparing data in a case-insensitive way - not whether T-SQL statements are case-sensitive.

Comment: The way it is worded, it sounds like he was asking if it was case sensitive.  I think the down vote is a little unfair there.

Comment: The query he provided makes it pretty clear what he's asking about.

Comment: I guess we will have to agree to disagree on that one

Comment: Looking at the OPs recent edit where he's talking about parameters and variables of mixed case, I think Mark's got a valid point here. It's not purely data in columns. Going to +1.

Comment: Did +1 but maybe expand as 'SQL Server is not case sensitive' is not entirely true as a broad statement when referring to data comparison

Comment: "SQL Server is not case sensitive" is not true. Whether SQL Server is case sensitive for data, *or for schema* (e.g. table names, field names) is dependent on collation settings. Remember that table names/field names are just metadata which is also affected by collation settings.

Comment: At MarkCallison: I doubt anyone would be asking whether Reserved Words are case-sensitive, but user-defined Identifiers would be a fair question.
@RobLevine: What about Variables (which I doubt are stored in System Tables at least not permanent ones) - is there there some SQL Server setting that would make *them* case-sensitive (ala C#)?