# How to find rows that have a value that contains a lowercase letter

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm looking for an SQL query that gives me all rows where ColumnX contains any lowercase letter (e.g. "1234aaaa5789"). Same for uppercase.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE UPPER(some_field) != some_field
```

This should work with funny characters like åäöøüæï. You might need to use a language-specific  utf-8 collation for the table.

Comment: It does not work in case insensitive DB, must add COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS from Devraj Gadhavi answer

Comment: In MySQL 5.6, `Latin1_General_CS_AS` caused an error. `COLLATE latin1_general_cs` worked though.

Comment: @kouton edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14646445/1184435) for more details on the issue you faced.

Comment: This doesn't work in MySQL without the BINARY adjective.  So: SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE BINARY UPPER(some_field) != BINARY some_field

Answer (score 55):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = 'my string'
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

This would make a case sensitive search.

---

**EDIT**

As stated in [kouton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094271/kouton)'s [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123418/how-to-find-rows-that-have-a-value-that-contains-a-lowercase-letter#comment60593577_4123562) and [tormuto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2298136/tormuto)'s [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123418/how-to-find-rows-that-have-a-value-that-contains-a-lowercase-letter#comment66301179_14646445) whosoever faces problem with the below collation

```
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

should first check the [default collation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1411161/1184435) for their SQL server, their respective database and the column in question; and pass in the default collation with the query expression. List of collations can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174596(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: This didn't work from my server's phpmyadmin; i got an error:  Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CS_AS'. So i had to use a more available collation instead 'Latin1_General_CS'  and it worked.

Comment: @tormuto edited the answer; and added some more details on the issue you faced. Though I am not sure whether it would work for MySQL, you might find something for MySQL similar to what MS SQL server offers.

Answer (score 43):

```
SELECT * FROM Yourtable 
WHERE UPPER([column_NAME]) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS !=[Column_NAME]
```

Comment: Cool, this worked for me on SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 27):

This is how I did it for utf8 encoded table and utf8_unicode_ci column, which doesn't seem to have been posted exactly:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE UPPER(column) != BINARY(column)
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer.  No need to fight the collation thing

Comment: Not working on SQL Server. Tried with not equal to with <>

Comment: not sure if this works on SQL Server, it was only tested on MySQL.

Comment: Super useful, thanks!

Comment: What is the SQL Server equivalent query for this?

Comment: @tRuEsAtM Sorry, no idea, but all you should need to find out is the equivalent method names for `upper` and `binary` in SQL Server.

Comment: This is the only one that works for me

Answer (score 15):

for search all rows in lowercase

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE col1 
LIKE '%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%'
collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Thanks [Manesh Joseph](http://maneshjoseph.blogspot.cl/2010/10/find-rows-with-lower-case-characters-in.html)

Comment: This solved my problem after I changed the comparison string to capitals.

Comment: This is very interesting.  I had tried this with '%[a-z]%', which does not work.  I have confirmed that spelling out every letter does work.

Answer (score 9):

IN MS SQL server use the COLLATE clause.

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'casesearch'
```

Adding `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` makes the search case sensitive.

Default Collation of the SQL Server installation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is not case sensitive.

To change the collation of the any column for any table permanently run following query.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ALTER COLUMN Column1 VARCHAR(20)
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

To know the collation of the column for any table run following Stored Procedure.

```
EXEC sp_help DatabaseName
```

Source : [SQL SERVER – Collate – Case Sensitive SQL Query Search](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/)

Answer (score 7):

I've done something like this to find out the lower cases.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
  where BINARY_CHECKSUM(lower(ColumnName)) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(ColumnName)
```

Comment: It's working fine in SQL

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql> SELECT '1234aaaa578' REGEXP '^[a-z]';
```

Comment: Will not work with any other characters than a-z, like åäöøüæï, etc.

Comment: FYI. REGEXP and RLIKE use the current character set when deciding the type of a character. The default is latin1 (cp1252 West European).

Warning
The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

Answer (score 3):

I have to add BINARY to the *ColumnX*, to get result as ***case sensitive***

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE BINARY(ColumnX) REGEXP '^[a-z]';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on MySQL I would suggest you look at `REGEXP`.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColumnX REGEXP '^[a-z]';
```

Answer (score 1):

In Posgresql you could use `~`

For example you could search for all rows that have `col_a` with any letter in lowercase

`select * from your_table where col_a '[a-z]';`

You could modify the Regex expression according your needs.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking Rohit's solution should have worked, but it didn't. I think SQL Management Studio messed up when trying to optimize this.

But by modifying the string before comparing them I was able to get the right results.  This worked for me:

```
SELECT [ExternalId]
FROM [EquipmentSerialsMaster] where LOWER('0'+[ExternalId]) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS != '0'+[ExternalId]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Firebird SQL, it should work in any SQL queries I believe, unless the underlying connection is not case sensitive.

To find records with any lower case letters:

```sql
select * from tablename where upper(fieldname) <> fieldname
```

To find records with any upper case letters:

```sql
select * from tablename where lower(fieldname) <> fieldname
```

Answer (score 0):

--For Sql

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE tablecolumnname LIKE '%[a-z]%';
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
SELECT * FROM programs WHERE LOWER(CODE) <> CAST(CODE AS BINARY)
```