# Extract all records with first character is lowercase

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with person's information.
I need to extract all person's who have their FirstName column's first character starting with lowercase.

```
-- Persons
Mike
Peter
andrew
jason
Elena

-- Output
andrew
jason
```

Thanx in advance. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Further to nscheaffer's answer. There are many ways this can be done. Check out http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/case-sensitive-search-fetching-lowercase-or-uppercase-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it on this link

[How to find rows that have a value that contains a lowercase letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123418/how-to-find-rows-that-have-a-value-that-contains-a-lowercase-letter)

> IN MS SQL server use the COLLATE clause as mentioned in this post:
>
> http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

```
select *
from PersonsTable
where ascii(left(Name, 1)) between 97 and 122
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, by checking the first character of the string.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.FirstName 
FROM dbo.tblPersons p
WHERE LEFT(p..FirstName, 1) = LOWER(LEFT(p..FirstName, 1)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use IF test not in ( ABCDEF...) in your main programme :

list  = { A,B ....

if(! list.contains(name.substring(1)){

}

Comment: Hi Chakib, welcome to Stackoverflow. Although answers are appreciated, this question is for MSSQL and not Java.