# help with sql server '05 query statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a select statement for my autocomplete function(s). I want to take the prefix text from the given text box and pull the first 10 items who's beginning characters matches the prefix. I could probably figure it out on my own, but its getting only the first 10 matches that loses me. Any solutions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did that give you? Why was that the wrong results? What do you think is the most likely reason it is wrong?

Comment: Um, I don't even know where to begin when it comes to stopping the query after so many matches have been found, so nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the SQL working to pull the list back from the DB, just add "top 10" to the SQL... like

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE LName like 'Smi%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server is case-insensitive unless you specify that as an installation option. That's a factor of the collation options. Here's an SO question on that topic: [SQL Server check case-sensitivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity)

To get the top ten results:

SET @searchValue = @searchValue + '%'

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Items WHERE ItemName LIKE @searchValue ORDER BY ItemName

Comment: Yeah..I just realized its not case sensitive to begin with. I edited my question, I apologize