# select query using multiple like conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

Below is an existing ms sql server 2008 report query.

```
SELECT
    number, batchtype, customer, systemmonth, systemyear, entered, comment, totalpaid
FROM
    payhistory LEFT OUTER JOIN agency ON
        payhistory.SendingID = agency.agencyid      
WHERE
    payhistory.batchtype LIKE 'p%' AND
    payhistory.entered >= '2011-08-01 00:00:00.00' AND
    payhistory.entered <  '2011-08-15 00:00:00.00' AND
    payhistory.systemmonth = 8 AND
    payhistory.systemyear = 2011 AND
    payhistory.comment NOT LIKE 'Elit%'
```

Results will look like this:

```
number  batchtype   customer    systemmonth systemyear  entered     comment         totalpaid
6255756 PC      EMC1106     8       2011        12:00:00 AM DP From - NO CASH       33
5575317 PA      ERS002      8       2011        12:00:00 AM MO-0051381526 7/31      20
6227031 PA      FTS1104     8       2011        12:00:00 AM MO-10422682168 7/30     25
6232589 PC      FTS1104     8       2011        12:00:00 AM DP From - NO CASH       103
2548281 PC      WAP1001     8       2011        12:00:00 AM NCO DP $1,445.41        89.41
4544785 PCR     WAP1001     8       2011        12:00:00 AM NCO DP $1,445.41        39
```

What I am trying to do is modify the query that will exclude records where the customer is like 'FTS%' and 'EMC%' and batchtype = 'PC'. As you can see in the result set there are records where customer is like FTS% and batchtype = 'PA'. I would like to keep these records in the results. I would appreciate any ideas offered.

Comment: What are the undesired results you are getting?

Comment: So, why do you say "only when btype = 'PC'" and then put `btype <> 'PC'`?

Comment: Your SQL has an extra parenthesis, or it's missing one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query contains a mix of upper and lower string comparison targets.  As far as I'm aware, SQL Server is not by default case-sensitive; is it possible this is what is tripping your query up?  Check collation per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity/1411260#1411260).

EDIT: Based on your updated question, can you not just use an AND clause that uses a NOT on the front?
In other words, add a 'AND not (x)' clause, where 'x' is the conditions that define the records you want to exclude?  You'd need to nest the customer test, because it's an OR.
e.g.:

```
... payhistory.comment NOT LIKE 'Elit%'
AND not ((customer like 'FTS%' or customer like 'EMC%') AND batchtype = 'PC')
```

As a side note, I believe that a LIKE clause may imply an inefficient table scan in some (but [not all](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jnelson/archive/2007/11/16/108354.aspx)) cases, so if this query will be used in a performance-sensitive role you may want to check the query plan, and optimise the table to suit.

Comment: YES!! That is exactly what I needed to do. I spent too much time trying to put that statement together, not knowing I can use the "NOT" argument to filter out those records. Thanks to all!!

Comment: Great! Also - if it answers your question, can you mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql="select * from builder_property where builder_pro_name LIKE '%%' OR builder_pro_name LIKE '%za%' AND status='Active'";
```

This will return all the builder property name in table that will ends name like `plaza` or `complex`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because your sever might be case sensitive. In that case, below query would work.

```
SELECT
table1.number, table1.btype, table1.cust, table1.comment, table2.ACode
FROM
table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.1ID = table2.2ID
WHERE
lower(table1.btype) LIKE 'p%' AND
lower(table1.comment) NOT LIKE 'yyy%' AND
lower(table1.cust) NOT LIKE 'abc%' AND
lower(table1.cust) NOT LIKE 'xyz%' AND
lower(table1.btype) <> 'pc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition to the WHERE clause:

```
NOT((customer LIKE 'FTS%' OR customer LIKE 'EMC%') AND batchtype='PC')
```

Assuming your other results are OK and you just want to filter those out, the whole query would be

```
SELECT
    number, batchtype, customer, systemmonth, systemyear, entered, comment, totalpaid
FROM
    payhistory 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN agency ON
        payhistory.SendingID = agency.agencyid      
WHERE
    payhistory.batchtype LIKE 'p%' AND
    payhistory.entered >= '2011-08-01 00:00:00.00' AND
    payhistory.entered <  '2011-08-15 00:00:00.00' AND
    payhistory.systemmonth = 8 AND
    payhistory.systemyear = 2011 AND
    payhistory.comment NOT LIKE 'Elit%' AND
    NOT((payhistory.customer LIKE 'FTS%' OR payhistory.customer LIKE 'EMC%') AND payhistory.batchtype='PC')
```

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

When building complex where clauses it is a good idea to use parenthesis to keep everything straight. Also when using multiple **NOT LIKE** statements you have to combine all of the **NOT LIKE** conditions together using **ORs** and wrap them inside of a separate **AND** condition like this...

```
WHERE     
    (payhistory.batchtype LIKE 'p%')
AND (payhistory.entered >= '2011-08-01 00:00:00.00')
AND (payhistory.entered <  '2011-08-15 00:00:00.00')
AND (payhistory.systemmonth = 8 )
AND (payhistory.systemyear = 2011)
AND ( // BEGIN NOT LIKE CODE

    (payhistory.comment NOT LIKE 'Elit%') 

OR  (
    (payhistory.customer NOT LIKE 'EMC%') AND 
    (payhistory.batchtype = 'PC')
    ) 

OR  (
    (payhistory.customer NOT LIKE 'FTS%') AND 
    (payhistory.batchtype = 'PC')
    )

    ) //END NOT LIKE CODE
```