# Why do URL shorteners use uppercase letters, if using uppercase is discouraged in the path section of a URL?

Tags: url, uppercase, url-shortener

I just read in [this SO question about uppercase URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13511227/1663942) that it's good practice to avoid uppercase letters in the URL (especially in the path section).  However, shorteners like `bit.ly` produce urls like this:

```
http://bit.ly/1FVKCd9
```

(which is incidentally the same question I linked above).

Why is this?

Comment: They probably are base-64 encoded.

Comment: It allows them to use a base 62 alphabet as compared to a base 36 alphabet. This in turn allows them to generate shorter URLs.

Comment: Both of these should probably be answers - although it doesn't really address the issue of case-sensitive path sections in different OSes.