# Can't create page aem 6.3

Tags: aem

I'm using AEM,and meet a problem.

Firsly [follow these steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVM1j.png)

Secondly the page is below:
I create the page based on the Summit Toys Base Content Page template.

[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtl9E.png)

but click next button ,the page shows like below:

[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhDiu.png)

why and how to solve this issue.

Thanks advance!

Answer (score 2):

This should be your problem. From your [reference application](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/first_aem63_website.html#main-pars_header_1419004830), You have created a template under:

```
--apps
  -- summit_toys
     -- templates
```

and then the corresponding page rendering component under

```
  --apps
    -- summit_toys
      --components
        --structure
```

I am 90% sure, your page rendering component /apps/summit_toys/components/structure/contentpage is missing property `sling:resourceSuperType = wcm/foundation/components/page`. This brings the page properties dialog on the create page wizard. Check for spelling and case sensitive to exactly match above.

Other possibilities:

1. Make sure template sling:resourceType points to relative path of page rendering component (like summit_toys/components/structure/contentpage)
2. Check for typo, spelling errors. JCR standard prefers to keep all nodes in lower case ([for good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511227/url-structure-lower-case-vs-upper-case)). Make sure your nodes are lower case; hyphenated if required.

Issue should get resolved with sling:resourceSuperType = wcm/foundation/components/page. If still fails, you might need to share /apps package to check further.

Answer (score 0):

which version of aem you are using.
if it is 6.3, after creating your page, check if your page is there or not under content node in CRX
If it is there the check resource type is correctly mapped accordingly or not.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and is resolved
[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ycG.png)

issue is related to value of cq:allowedTemplate for /content/wetrain/jcr:content

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Please do not use links to pictures, but describe the solution in words.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur if you have not created dialog(cq:dialog) for your page component. Either you can create cq:dialog/ or extend out of the box page component using property sling:resourceSuperType as mentioned by Dhiraj Khursade.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using editable templates, check for `sling:resourceType` property under `/conf/<project>/settings/wcm/templates/<template-name>/structure/jcr:content` and `/conf/<project>/settings/wcm/templates/<template-name>/initial/jcr:content` both should point to correct page component `<project>/components/structure/<page-component>`

Also make sure that, page component has correct value for `sling:resourceSuperType` with valid page component from core components or wcm core component. Try creating fresh new page and validate instead of trying on existing page.