# Arcgis Esri are not diplaying on Map on the android device

Tags: java, android, arcgis, esri

Hie,,,,
I just downloaded arcgis pluggin to display map on andriod phone. When i created the map using the sample code (HelloWorld) , I change the url to [http://e1.onemap.sg/arcgis/rest/services/SN128/mapserver] and when i run the program, all i see is blank , i waited for almost 10-30mins but nothing is displaying on my phone.
I would appreciate if someone could really tell me where did i really go wrong .

**This are my Xml Codes**

```
<!-- MapView layout and initial extent -->
<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    initExtent = "-1.3296373526814876E7 3930962.41823043 -1.2807176545789773E7 4201243.7502468005">
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My HelloWorld Java Class is**

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
MapView mMapView = null;
ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tileLayer;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
    mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    /* create a @ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer */
    tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
            //"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
            "http://e1.onemap.sg/arcgis/rest/services/SN128/mapserver");
            // Add tiled layer to MapView
    mMapView.addLayer(tileLayer);

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 
    mMapView.unpause();
}
```

This is my LogCat

**THIS LOGCAT IS IN BLUE**

10-30 17:17:33.417: D/dalvikvm(10277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 234K, 8% free 9552K/10375K, paused 14ms+3ms, total 38ms
10-30 17:17:33.497: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277):    MapSurface initialize com.esri.android.map.MapSurface@41996608
10-30 17:17:33.497: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277): map.onChildViewAdded
10-30 17:17:33.497: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277): map.onChildViewAdded
10-30 17:17:33.502: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277): surface.addLayer ->http://e1.onemap.sg/arcgis/rest/services/SM128/mapserver

---

**THIS LOGCAT IS IN RED COLOR**

10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277): url =http://e1.onemap.sg/arcgis/rest/services/SM128/mapserver
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277): com.esri.core.io.EsriServiceException: Not Found
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at com.esri.core.internal.io.handler.c.a(Unknown Source)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at com.esri.core.internal.io.handler.g$1.handleResponse(Unknown Source)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at com.esri.core.internal.io.handler.g$1.handleResponse(Unknown Source)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:773)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:743)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at com.esri.core.internal.io.handler.g.a(Unknown Source)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at com.esri.core.internal.io.handler.g.a(Unknown Source)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at com.esri.core.internal.tasks.a.p.a(Unknown Source)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.initLayer(Unknown Source)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer$1.run(Unknown Source)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-30 17:17:33.532: E/ArcGIS(10277):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

---

**AND THIS IS IN BLUE BACK**

10-30 17:17:33.542: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277): map.onSizechanged
10-30 17:17:33.547: D/(10277): Device driver API match
10-30 17:17:33.547: D/(10277): Device driver API version: 10
10-30 17:17:33.547: D/(10277): User space API version: 10 
10-30 17:17:33.547: D/(10277): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012 
10-30 17:17:33.562: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277): >  MapSurface.Context created. com.esri.android.map.MapSurface@41996608
10-30 17:17:33.562: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277):    MapSurface unpaused
10-30 17:17:33.587: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277):    MapSurface SurfaceCreated
10-30 17:17:33.587: D/ArcGIS.LifeCycle(10277):    MapSurface SurfaceChanged:480,724
10-30 17:17:33.592: D/ArcGIS.Lock(10277): >> MapView wait for surface.loaded
10-30 17:17:33.592: D/ArcGIS.Lock(10277): !! MapView lock surface.loaded

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using exclusively Microsoft software--and ArcGIS is from Esri, not Microsoft--you need to remember that [URLs are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996919/should-url-be-case-sensitive).

http://e1.onemap.sg/arcgis/rest/services/SM128/mapserver

is not the same as

http://e1.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/SM128/MapServer

Click them both to open in a browser and see what happens.

Try the second one and your app should work.

Comment: hie, thank you. but when i run it, all i see is in blue of color .. the map doesnt appear. is there anything i have change with the map lat and log in order for me to display the map.?

Comment: Hey , i just get it. Thanks for the help. really appreaciate it. C: