# Font face not working on web server

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been trying to fix my problem regarding my fonts on my current project. The website can't seem to locate the fonts that i have uploaded yet on my localhost the fonts seem to be working. The path is also the same as one in the localhost and when i check it on firebug I'm getting a network error which is weird

and here is my CSS code in applying the font

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'kulturistaregular';
    src: url('fonts/kulturista/kulturista_medium-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/kulturista/kulturista_medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/kulturista/kulturista_medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/kulturista/kulturista_medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/kulturista/kulturista_medium-webfont.svg#kulturistaregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Here is the link for my current project

```
http://192.163.215.153/baronpage/
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I encountered similar issues with fonts on Localhost when using IE9...

Comment: I'm using mozilla, I also tried it on chrome but no luck

Comment: is your online version a direct copy of your localhost version? No changes to filepaths or file structure?

Comment: yes no changes on the file path. The path is basically the same as the localhost

Comment: Have you tried only applying one font at a time? Bearing in mind certain browsers will only recognise certain font formats. I'd try every browser you can get your hands on to be certain.

Comment: It's only one font. The rest of the fonts are coming from google fonts. I can't find the font I'm looking for on google fonts so i had to use fontsquirrel to convert it into web-font and upload it

Comment: Sorry, I should have said only source one font file at a time, so just try `'fonts/kulturista/kulturista_medium-webfont.eot'`, then `.woff`, then `.ttf` etc

Comment: @clestcruz define `MIME` type for WOFF fonts on your IIS server.

Comment: same outcome. It didn't work

Comment: what MIME Type you define?

Comment: @kheema I'm sorry I'm not very familiar with servers. I'm using bluehost at the moment when it comes to uploading websites. Where exactly do I define the MIME type

Comment: you can ask your server provider your website have custom fonts. so need to define the MIME TYPE for `WOFF` font..

Comment: I just put your font on my site and it works fine.

Comment: really? hmmm i wonder if it has something to do with the address of my current project http://192.163.215.153/baronpage/

Answer (score 0):

I dug around in your project and noticed that the main `kulturista` folder is spelt with a capital K (`Kulturista`). Perhaps case-sensitivity in your hosting environment is preventing those assets from being loaded?

Here is a (possibly) related stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17113291/2803192

Comment: I tried changing it to Capital "K" in the folder but no luck. I even tried adding ../fonts on the src