# Why xml.etree.ElementTree does not support namespace URI case change

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse XML, where the URI for the same namespace is not using the same case. (some xml owners decided to lower-case URIs). If I parse data with one type of URI followed by data with the other type, the parser fail finding my data although I update the ns dictionary to match the document URI... Here is an example:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

DATA_lc = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<container xmlns:roktatar="http://www.example.com/lower/case/bug">
<item>
   <roktatar:author>Boby Mac Gallinger</roktatar:author>
</item>
</container>'''

DATA_UC = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<container xmlns:roktatar="http://www.example.com/Lower/Case/Bug">
<item>
   <roktatar:author>John-John Le Grandiosant</roktatar:author>
</item>
</container>'''

tree = ET.parse(StringIO(DATA_lc))
root = tree.getroot()
ns = {'roktatar': 'http://www.example.com/lower/case/bug'}
for item in root.iter('item'):
    print item.find('roktatar:author', namespaces=ns).text.strip()

tree = ET.parse(StringIO(DATA_UC))
root = tree.getroot()
ns = {'roktatar': 'http://www.example.com/Lower/Case/Bug'}
for item in root.iter('item'):
    print item.find('roktatar:author', namespaces=ns).text.strip()
```

If each parsing block is processed on it's own, the data gets collected properly, but if they come next to each others, the second always fail. I am missing so reset/cleaning of the parser between documents? Is this a Bug?

Thanks

Comment: Paths in URLs are **not** case insensitive. You actually have **different** namespaces here. See [Should url be case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7996919)

Comment: I agree with you @Martjin, the question should be narrowed to why elementtree does not support changing URI for the same namespace?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean here; there is a cache that needs clearing. I'll write an answer.

Comment: As written, it sounds like you're asking a question about the design of `ElementTree`, which was answered in Martijn's first comment. If you're actually asking how to change URLs for the same namespace, ask that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ElementTree search code parses arguments to `find()` and related functions for XPath expressions, and *caches* the resulting closed-over functions for reuse.

When you search for a `roktatar:author`, that expression is cached as a search for `'{http://www.example.com/lower/case/bug}author'`, but in your second document the binding changed.

In other words, ElementTree assumes that the same namespace prefix will *always* map to the same namespace URI.

The better solution to this problem is to use a *different* prefix here, like `roktatar_uc` for the title-case version of the URL:

```
ns = {'roktatar_uc': 'http://www.example.com/Lower/Case/Bug'}
for item in root.iter('item'):
    print item.find('roktatar_uc:author', namespaces=ns).text.strip()
```

but if that is not an option, you'll have to clear the cache instead:

```
from xml.etree import ElementPath

ElementPath._cache.clear()
```

Comment: I have to use the _cache.clear() method: I do not have control over the XMLs. Thanks, I guess this is documented in ElementPath but I was far from looking there!

Comment: @Fafaman: You may not be able to alter the namespaces in the XML, but you *can* alter your `namespaces` dictionary and prefix.