# why the browser convert the capital letter to lowercase letter?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee

this is the url of my login page : /CarthagoWeb/login.html
 I don't know why the browser convert the capital letter to lowercase letter it look like this : /carthagoweb/login.html ,and that's wrong

could anyone help me please !

Comment: What browser is this?  Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996919/should-url-be-case-sensitive for a related discussion (although not directly a duplicate)

Comment: Is your web server running Apache or IIS?  If you're running a Windows variant, capital/lowercase letters are interchangeable, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: because the C for carthago must be a capital letter and the same for the W !

Comment: How do requests pass through from browser to JBoss, did you have intermediary reverse proxy server (apache / IIS) ?

Comment: it works before and the browser doesn't convert the capital letters , i don't know why it convert them now ? , 
and that's wrong because the path of login page is changing :((

Comment: I didn't change nothing , i just added another server (tomcat) for another project

Comment: when i run the login page in eclipse , it's ok (the path is correct) ! but when i put the url in the browser the path change!  :(

Comment: it worke in mozilla firefox! but i doesn't work in chrome and opera
!! have you any explication please ?