# Why uppercase isn't usual in URL

Tags: url, uppercase, lowercase

I've visited many sites that most of them used lowercase in URLs like

```
stackoverflow.com/questions
google.com/webmaster
bing.com/news
```

Why using uppercase isn't more prevalent? Is there a problem using uppercase in URL? Is this a programming language problem?

Comment: It's just convention. Capital letters are commonly used in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Wikipedia), [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/YouTube) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Support) URLs if the article/channel/username has capital letters. All caps are rarely used because it's considered loud and harsh, but there is nothing technical preventing it.

Comment: I've seen buggy bots convert URLs to lowercase. This caused a very special bug with code decompressing data encoded in the URL that wasn't validated, first. Some websites (notably reddit) use base-36 encoded IDs to avoid this.

Comment: Related question on [webmasters.se]: [Should my URLs be lowercase?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/51702/17633)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should URL be case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996919/should-url-be-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 12):

URLs are generally case-insensitive and lowercase is used only for stylistic purposes and so it doesn't look like URLs are yelling at you. You can still find uppercase letters in URLs. For example, Amazon product pages use numbers and uppercase letters for the product ID. You can change the letters to lowercase and the same page loads.

Comment: One more reason is to make the URL easy to remember. English had 26 alphabets but when you consider small and capital case distinct it grows to 52.

Comment: I think that's because Amazon are searching by upper and lower case for their products IDs

Answer (score 8):

**URLs are not case sensitive up to a point.**

A URL of `Foo.Bar` will be treated the same as `foo.bar` and `FOO.BAR`. However, if a URL contains characters of a different case *after* the domain (`.bar` in my example), it is possible that changing the case of those characters will result in an error.

So, if a URL is provided as `foo.bar/Baz`, and you try to access `foo.bar/baz`, you risk accessing the wrong resource or encountering an error.

Remember that URLs with forward slash characters following the domain (as in `foo.bar/baz`) are treated (at least on the front end) as pointers to directories in a file system, and case sensitivity will be dependent on the file system the web server is using.

Comment: Interesting, so we should care about SEO - page duplicates can happen on urls which differs only with case of letters...