# How to use css selector with "not" in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to find elements by css selector, but I want to skip some of them, how can I do it?

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]"))
```

but I need not to take href that has logoff and client/contract in it

Comment: You really don't need LINQ for this. Just use the `:not()` pseudo. Read up on it.

Comment: but how it will look if I want to skip more than one thing? Like "a[href]:not(apple or banana)"

Comment: If it's `not(apple or banana)` then it is both `not(apple)` and `not(banana)`, and hence `:not(apple):not(banana)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need LINQ for this. You can use the `:not()` pseudo-class, one for each value you want to exclude (note the `*=` in each negation; I'm assuming substring matches here):

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]:not([href*='logoff']):not([href*='client'])"))
```

An exception is if you have a dynamic list of values that you want to exclude: you can either build your selector programmatically using `string.Join()` or a loop and then pass it to `By.CssSelector()`, or you can follow Richard Schneider's answer using LINQ to keep things clean.

Answer (score 1):

After using CSS to get the elements then use LINQ to filter on the `href`.

```
Using System.Linq;

string[] blackList = new string[] { "logoff, "client",... };
string[] urls = driver
  .FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[href]"))
  .Select(e => e.GetAttribute("href"))
  .Where(url => !blackList.Any(b => url.Contains(b)))
  .ToArray();
```

Checking the URL is case-sensitive, because that is what [W3C states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996919/should-url-be-case-sensitive). You may want to change this.