# Selenium select several elements except some class

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

When working with OpenQA.Selenium, I need to FindElement() by a CssSelector.
That's easy in the case of the folded or multiple classes.

```
<div class="myClass andMore">
    <div class="hey">
        <div class "deeper">
            inner text 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hey bad">
        <div class "deeper">
            inner text 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hey">
        <div class "deeper">
            inner text 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To get "inner text 2", I can do the following:

```
string innerTxt2 = browserClient.FindElement(By.CssSelector("myClass.andMore .hey.bad .deeper"))
                                .Text;
```

however, I can't understand how to select **all** "hey" **except the** "hey bad", and then select texts inside of their "deeper" divs.

I want to get:

```
List<string> text1_and_text3 = browserClient.FindElement(By.CssSelector("myClass.andMore.hey:not('hey.bad').deeper)
                                            .Select(el=>el.Text)
                                            .ToList()"
```

However, an exception is thrown, saying "not a valid selector"
Tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816598/how-to-use-css-selector-with-not-in-c) and [this one](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/) but no luck

I need to do this purely with css selector query (would like minimum Linq / for-loops)

Answer (score 2):

You can get all you need by using xpath:

```
browserClient.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'hey') and not(contains(@class, 'bad'))]/div")
```