# jQuery Github Site

Tags: jquery, github

Have images served up based on user choice via the dropdown box.
Works locally, however, after committing to Github website the images are no longer being served.
Developer tool does not show an error. 
Hovering over the image link simply states 'Could not load the image'.
Source link is accurate and other static image loads properly.
Any ideas as to why this is happening and/or possibly how to fix it?

```
var pictureList = [
    "../img/alabama.png",
    "../img/alaska.png",
    "../img/arizona.png",
    "../img/arkansas.png",
    "../img/california.png",
    "../img/colorado.png",
    "../img/Connecticut.png",
    "../img/Delaware.png",
    "../img/Florida.png",
    "../img/Georgia.png",
    "../img/Hawaii.png",
    "../img/Idaho.png",
    "../img/Illinois.png",
    "../img/Indiana.png",
    "../img/Iowa.png",
    "../img/Kansas.png",
    "../img/Kentucky.png",
    "../img/Louisiana.png",
    "../img/Massachusetts.png",
    "../img/Maryland.png",
    "../img/Maine.png",
    "../img/Michigan.png",
    "../img/Minnesota.png",
    "../img/Missouri.png",
    "../img/Mississippi.png",
    "../img/Montana.png",
    "../img/North Carolina.png",
    "../img/North Dakota.png",
    "../img/Nebraska.png",
    "../img/New Hampshire.png",
    "../img/New Jersey.png",
    "../img/New Mexico.png",
    "../img/Nevada.png",
    "../img/New York.png",
    "../img/Ohio.png",
    "../img/Oklahoma.png",
    "../img/Oregon.png",
    "../img/Pennsylvania.png",
    "../img/Rhode Island.png",
    "../img/South Carolina.png",
    "../img/South Dakota.png",
    "../img/Tennessee.png",
    "../img/Texas.png",
    "../img/Utah.png",
    "../img/Virginia.png",
    "../img/Vermont.png",
    "../img/Washington.png",
    "../img/Wisconsin.png",
    "../img/West Virginia.png",
    "../img/Wyoming.png", ];

var $sc = $('#state_area')

$('#picDD').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $sc.children('img').attr("src", pictureList[val-1]);
})
```

Comment: Looks like the image requests are throwing 404 errors. Are you sure the relative paths are resolving correctly to the actual image URLs? Check your browser's dev tool's network tab. What do you see?

Comment: You are right, 404 errors are being thrown, however, the static image on the page "../img/uspopcan.PNG"  loads without a problem...Could the capitalized letters make the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing on your Github page ;), I came to the conclusion the path is case sensitive.

This doesn't work: `https://eclecticexistential.github.io/img/Hawaii.png`

This does work: `https://eclecticexistential.github.io/img/Hawaii.PNG`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996997/5686835) answer also verifies that identifiers should be handled with capitalization in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much ^_^!