# Rest API redirects to default swagger petstore api when capitalization changes in url

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I've got swagger added to my Startup.cs file and it shows my api just fine except when someone changes the capitalization of the word "Help" in the url. If I put in the url like this:
https://sitename/Help/index.html
This takes me to my correct api documentation, but if I put in this:
https://sitename/help/index.html
This takes me to the default swagger petstore api

Can anyone help me out with this?  The company I work for is requesting it to work the same with or without capitalizing "Help"

Comment: Could you paste the swagger options without the sensitive data, please?

Comment: Which swagger package are you using and which version?

Comment: You may need to set up a 301 redirect from lowercase `/help/*` to `/Help/*`. URLs are [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996997/113116) in general so technically `/help` and `/Help` are two different URLs.

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewrite Middleware can be used for this purpose. The middleware allows to modify request URLs based on predefined rules. The middleware is provided by the  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite` package, which is found in the ASP.NET Core applications by default.

URL rewrite rules can be established by creating chained instances of `RewriteOptions` and passing them into the URL Rewrite Middleware.

By adding the following code segment into Configure method of Startup.cs, the re-writing of url from `/Help/index.html` to `/help/index.html` can be achieved.

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirect("^Help/(.*)", "help/$1");
            
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Here is how it looks after introducing the URL rewrite option:

Original request: `/Help/index.html`

[image]