# Does capital letters in URl matter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, iis, web-deployment

Recently I cam across a scenario.

When I tried to access the below URL on the host server, it gave me a 500 internal server error.

```
<DomainAddress>/tut/Courses/CoursesView
```

But when I change the URL as below it worked(Changed 't' to 'T').

```
<DomainAddress>/Tut/Courses/CoursesView
```

I understand that tut is a folder on the server.

1. While trying to access an application do capital letters matter ?
2. Am I missing some settings in the IIS server ?

**Project details**

- MVC application.
- CourseView is a HttpPostMethod.
- Also the following  url works on my localserver

  /Courses/CoursesView

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should URL be case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996919/should-url-be-case-sensitive)

Comment: So URLs are supposed to be case sensitive. This does not answer my questions because I am trying to understand why captilization matters in a url .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Section 6.2.2.1 of RFC 3986** says that "*scheme and host are case-insensitive and therefore should be normalized to lowercase*. For example, the URI HTTP://www.EXAMPLE.com/ is equivalent to http://www.example.com/.

Some web servers (usually Unix servers) consider all URLs to be case sensitive. That is, they would treat each of the following URLs as referring to a different file and web page:

http://www.example.com/mypage.html

http://www.example.com/MyPage.html

http://www.example.com/MYPAGE.html

http://www.example.com/MYPAGE.HTML

If you visited “http://www.example.com/mypage.html” but the file was actually named “MyPage.html”, these kinds of servers would display a “file not found” error.

But other web servers (mostly Windows servers) would treat all these URLs as requests for the same file, because they use a file system that doesn’t care about capitalization. Using an incorrectly capitalized link on these kinds of servers doesn’t cause an error.

A server might also normalize the passed URI internally and serve the same resource for URIs of different case (/about/ and /ABOUT/), making an URI appear case-insensitive to the user.