# Oracle to SQL Server conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

What is the equivalent of SQL Server query form for the below Oracle query in a `LIKE` statement:

```
((UPPER(ADDRESS) like '%'|| UPPER(:VALUE1) || '%' ) OR (ADDRESS IS NULL AND :VALUE1 IS NULL))
```

I am stuck  with the syntax `'%'||------||'%'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+` instead of `||` to concatenate the strings

```
((UPPER(ADDRESS) like '%'+ UPPER(VALUE1) + '%' ) OR (ADDRESS IS NULL AND VALUE1 IS NULL))
```

You also do not need to use upper in comparison for SQL Server. Comparisons in SQL Server are case insensitive.

Is this part of a where clause or something?

Comment: Yes Pat , It is in Where clause only ..Thank you

Comment: by default SQL Server is case insensitive, but there are case sensitive collations also. e.g. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

`||` is Oracle's concatenation operator. SQL Server's equivilent is `+`.

```
((UPPER(ADDRESS) like '%' + UPPER(@VALUE1) + '%' ) 
OR (ADDRESS IS NULL AND @VALUE1 IS NULL))
```

Incidentally, `||` is the SQL standard, `+` is used by some databases, like [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh501243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of following the standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
((UPPER(ADDRESS) like '%' + UPPER(VALUE1) + '%' ) OR (ADDRESS IS NULL AND VALUE1 IS NULL))
```

Note that using upper is only necessary depending on the collation setting.