# Finding a case sensitive record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to fetch case sensitive records from only one column of a table.

i.e their is a column email_address from which i have to find the email address which are same but they are in different cases.

for eg:

```
email_ address
---------------
abc@gmail.com
hef@gmail.com
ABC@gmail.com
hrf@gmail.com
```

from the above example given.I need a query to fetch only the records `abc@gmail.com` and `ABC@gmail.com` from the column `email_address`.

Comment: What database platform are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL..etc?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Don't you mean case *insensitive*?

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Comment: `LEFT SELF JOIN` using `<>` and `UPPER()=UPPER`.

Comment: How about mixed cases? like Abc@gmail.com ?

Comment: Yes,mixed cases are also one of the condition.

Comment: Is the database collation case sensitive or insensitive?

Comment: This would Answer your Question - **[Link](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm)**

Answer (score 1):

Personally i don't like this approach, but it seems to be the only solution i have right now, and it works with mixed cases too  :

```
select * from test t 
    where   
    email_address in 
    (
    select email_address from test group by email_address having count(email_address)> 1        
    )
    and left(email_address, charindex('@', email_address) -1 ) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
        not in (select left(email_address, charindex('@', email_address) -1 ) from test 
                        where email_address collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS <> t.email_address )
```

p/s : u need to replace the "test" with your actual table's name

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table T 
JOIN    tALBE T2 
ON      T.EMAIL             =   T2.EMAIL
AND  CONVERT(varbinary,T.EMAIL)    <>       CONVERT(varbinary,T2.EMAIL)
```

Comment: It might help to explain your answer

Comment: It works only when case is complete lower or upper for mixed it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your DB is not case sensitive, but you need to find values that are the same, but in a different case, this might work -

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT
email_address 
FROM TEST
GROUP BY email_address
Having count(1) > 1
)
SELECT TEST.email_address 
FROM TEST
INNER JOIN CTE ON
TEST.email_address=CTE.email_address
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d390/3)

Answer (score 1):

Use Following condition

```
Where [email_ address] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Select * from TableName where email_ address COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'Your I/p Values'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
( VALUES ('abc'), ('ABC'), ('AbC')
) x(name)
WHERE name COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AI = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways we can Finding a case sensitive record 
1.using COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
2.using BINARY_CHECKSUM

```
create table EmailDetails(EID int identity(1,1),EmailAddress varchar(100))
insert into EmailDetails values('abc@gmail.com')
insert into EmailDetails values('ABC@gmail.com')
select EmailAddress from EmailDetails 
where EmailAddress COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI=LOWER(EmailAddress)
select EmailAddress from EmailDetails 
  where EmailAddress COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI='abc@gmail.com'
select EmailAddress from EmailDetails 
where BINARY_CHECKSUM(EmailAddress)=BINARY_CHECKSUM('abc@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer,

```
declare @t table(email varchar(100))

insert into @t values('abc@gmail.com'),('hef@gmail.com'),('ABC@gmail.com'),('hrf@gmail.com')

declare @searchEmail varchar(100 )= 'ABC@gmail.com'

---1st approach 
SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE   
    email = @searchEmail COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

---2nd approach to convert in binary
select * from @t where CAST(email  as varbinary(100))  =  CAST(@searchEmail as varbinary(100))
```

Can be done via changing the Collation, by default it is case insensitive.

By using collation or casting to binary, like this:

Check the same answer ask here ..

[How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause (I'm using SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server)

[SQL Server check case-sensitivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity)

Answer (score 0):

Use A wildcard sql query operator or command.. I am not sure what it is called i forgot.. you use it by adding "`%`" sign both on left and right part of your `WHERE` variable like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = %@VARIABLE%
```

hope this helps