# Login with SQL Server in Java

Tags: java, sql

I just started studying the connection between Java and SQL Server.
I have created multiple accounts in my login_DB database. But only the first record results in a successful login.

My question is how do I make it accept the other accounts?
I believe my problem is in the code but I'm weak at fixing logic errors.
Here's my code:

```
try {
    if(e.getSouce()==loginButton){
        String user = usernameTF.getText().trim();
        String pass = passwordTF.getText().trim();
        String sqlLogin = "select username , 
                                   pssword 
                           from tblLogin 
                           where username = '"+user+"'
                           and pssword = '"+pass+"'";
         rs = st.executeQuery(sqlLogin);
        int count = 0;  
            while(rs.next()){
                count+=1;
            }//while
            if(count==1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful!");
                mainFrame.dispose();
                firstPage page1 = new firstPage();  
            }
```

`tblogin`:

```
create table tblLogin ( username nvarchar(50) NULL, pssword nvarchar(50) NULL )

username    password 
Jerlon      hello 
buenconsejo jerlon 
jujux       jerlon 
jujux       jerlon 
Buenconsejo jerlon 
NULL        NULL
```

Comment: all the username is unique in the table right? so it will return only one row everytime according to the username typed in the texbox..can u show some sample?

Comment: if you show us data in `tblogin` table it will be easy to answer

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should use PreparedStatement.

Comment: @Sachu Like this ?
**username**      **password**
Jerlon         hello
buenconsejo jerlon
jujux            jerlon
jujux                 jerlon
Buenconsejo jerlon
NULL NULL

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli '
create table tblLogin
(
username nvarchar(50)  NULL,
pssword nvarchar(50) NULL

)
'Am I doing it right?

Comment: @Juju u have multiple user with username jerlon..it is not good in login table..u should make username as unique..will any site allow you to register with a username which is already in use?

Comment: @Sachu actually those 'jerlon' were passwords D:.

Comment: Then jujux is repeating username

Comment: @Sachu And also it is only a Java Project with some event handling xD 
And yes, I haven't created anything exception for a duplicate users :P

Comment: @Juju so ur pgm is working fine..

Comment: Is your SQL Server case sensitive?  Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity).   If it is not case sensitive, login with 'buenconsejo' and 'jujux' will fail.

Comment: Can `(count>=1)` solve it? ;).

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad design.

First, do not use + to create query. This is a bug allowing sql injection. Use `PreparedStatement` to create query with parameters from user.

Do not store password in plain text. Use hash (e.g. md5).

Use limit 1 for select statement (or `count(*)`)

Do not use `while` for `ResultSet`. Use `if` statement.

```
if(rs.next()) {
}
```

This is a sql example:

```
select * from tblLogin 
where username = ? and password = md5(?)
limit 1
```

**edit**: It is not a problem (logical problem) to use users with some name (or some password) if use unique key for username and password.

Comment: I would like to know what does md5(?) and limit 1 means. And also right now, I created a method that would get my sql statement 
'public void getQuery(String query){

  try{
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=login_DB;integratedSecurity=true");
   st=con.createStatement();
   st.executeUpdate(query);
  }//try
  catch(Exception ee){
   ee.printStackTrace();
  }//catch
  
 }//getQuery()
 '
Is that okay?

Comment: First, sorry for may bad English :( md5 is a function witch return md5 hash from input. This increases security by reducing the chance passwords to be stolen, because no one can see them (even administrator sql server). The limit statement restricts the result (in this case 1) because only one checking account (it's optimization, as well as the replacement of `while` with `if`). In your code, critical place is building the query is submitted to getQuery. To say that is OK you have to show how we create.