# Linq query not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2012

I have a very simple linq query which is as following:

```
var result = (from r in employeeRepo.GetAll()
              where r.EmployeeName.Contains(searchString) 
                    || r.SAMAccountName.Contains(searchString)
              orderby r.EmployeeName
              select new SelectListItem 
              { 
                  Text = r.EmployeeName, 
                  Value = r.EmployeeName 
              });
```

The issue is for some strange reason it fetches me the record of every person who I search for whether in lower case or upper case. i.e.

1. test user
2. Test User
3. TEST USER

I will get back the correct records. However when I search for my own name using lower case I don't get any results back but if I use the first letter of my name as upper case then I get the results. I can't seem to figure out why its doing that.

Every first and last name in the database start with upper case.

The searchString which I'm using are:

1. `richard` - I get correct results
2. `waidande` - no results found

Both of the above users are in the database.

I'm also using `Entity Framework` to query `Sql Server 2012`.

Comment: Can you show the exact data and the value of `searchString` that does seem to do a case insensitive match and then the one that seems to do a case sensitive match.  Also what is `employeeRepo`?  Is it some type of Linq to SQL provider?

Comment: @juharr the one that matches is `richard` the one that doesnt match is `waidande` and `GetAll()` is `IEnumerable<T> GetAll();`

Comment: Can it be related with your SQL Server's case sensitivity settings?

Comment: Please include the relevant data as well in your question.  Specifically is there a "Richard" and "Waidande" values in your collection or DB.

Comment: @OrkunBekar but it works for everyone else but my name

Comment: But what is `employeeRepo`?  It's important to know if this is EF or not as Linq can behave completely differently if you are using a provider that's translating it to SQL versus running it in code.

Comment: @juharr sorry my bad `employeeRepo` is EF

Comment: In that case as @OrkunBekar mentioned the DB will control case sensitivity.  Though it's still not clear what is going on as you seem to be seeing both case insensitive and case sensitive comparisons.

Comment: @juharr How can I check the control case sensitivity on the DB?

Comment: Here's a question about that for SQL Server.  If you're using a different DB then I'm sure you can google for something similar.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity

Comment: Have you tried actually running a SQL query?  It would be something like `Select * From EmployeeRepo Where EnployeeName Like '%richard%' Or SAMAccountName Like '%richard%'`  Then copy and paste the other value in there to see what the results are.  I doubt this is a case issue and more likely there are some special characters either in your DB or search string that are throwing it off.

Comment: Maybe for all but your own entry, the "SAMAccountName" contains the searchstring in all lowercase?

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: @OrifKhodjaev Using sql server 2012

Comment: *whether in lower case or upper case* - quite weird if, as you say, `GetAll()` is `IEnumerable<T> GetAll();`, making this a plain .Net match.

Comment: Maybe this is your case [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/466238)

Comment: @lad2025 Yeah, or "waidаndе". The date of the question raises suspicions :) Are you going to give the clue?

Comment: @GertArnold The clue is very simple `а` != `a` :)

Comment: Just in case this may really be an issue the OP isn't aware of: @Izzy, any chance you have Cyrillic characters in there?

Comment: @GertArnold I've debugged through and the value that is being passed is `waidаndе` without any spaces or special characters

Comment: The second 'а' and the 'е' are Cyrillic characters (code 1072 and 1077, in stead of the expected 97 and 101, respectively).

Comment: @lad2025 Are you going to compose an answer? it's your catch!

Comment: @GertArnold You should compose an answer as it's a very good catch and may help some of the future readers

Comment: @Izzy, please note that my answer, which was here first :-) also contains the point about symbols looking the same, but having different code point - see point #2, so please mark my suggestion as answer as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your text has `NVARCHAR` datatype check for similiar letters that in reality are not the same:

```
CREATE TABLE #employee (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), EmployeeName NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #employee(EmployeeName) VALUES (N'waidаnde');

SELECT *
FROM #employee
WHERE EmployeeName LIKE '%waidande%';

-- checking
SELECT *
FROM #employee
WHERE CAST(EmployeeName AS VARCHAR(100)) <> EmployeeName;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=69744f90783b09465b52705ee689da9f)**

Here: `'а'` != `'a'`. One is from `Cyrillic` `'a'` and the second is normal.

---

Idea taken from:

[image]

<sup>Slide from: http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event12/Revenge_The_SQL</sup>

P.S. I highly recommend to watch **Rob Volk's talk: `Revenge: The SQL!`**.

Answer (score 6):

To troubleshoot the issue, determine whether the problem is on the EF side, or on DB side.
A common mistake is extra whitespace, so make sure it's not the case before proceeding.

First check what query is being generated by EF, you can use one of the following methods to do this

1. [ObjectQuery.ToTraceString() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [EF logging of intercepted db calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx)
3. [Sql server profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181091(v=sql.120).aspx)

If you are using EF correctly and your query is translated to SQL as expected and contains the predicates in the where section, but you still are not getting any meaningful results, here are some ideas to try out on the DB side:

1. Check [collation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(v=sql.80).aspx) ( be aware it can be set on server, database and individual column level) - beware of case sensitivity and code page that is being used
2. Verify that your search string contains symbols that can be interpreted in the db code page - for example if code page is 252 - Windows Latin 1 ANSI and you are sending input with symbols from UTF-16 that are outside ANSI - you won't get any results, even though the symbols look the same
3. Highly improbable, but as last resort check if one of your queries has not been cached, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 (SQL Server) is installed by default with case insensitive collation. If you need to retrieve records from the database using case sensitivity (because you have "several" records) you need to change the collation (take care because if you change DBMS collation you change also master database collation so also tables and field names become case sensitive).
If you don't need to avoid to retrieve all the records from the DBMS you can just filter records after you retrieve them, i.e.

```
var result = (from r in employeeRepo.GetAll()
          where r.EmployeeName.Contains(searchString) 
                || r.SAMAccountName.Contains(searchString)
          orderby r.EmployeeName
          select new SelectListItem 
          { 
              Text = r.EmployeeName, 
              Value = r.EmployeeName 
          })
          .ToList()  // Materialize records and apply case sensitive filter
          .Where(r.EmployeeName.Contains(searchString) 
                || r.SAMAccountName.Contains(searchString));
```