# Stored procedure showing only 1 result

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Trying to make a stored procedure using sql and phpMyAdmin. Here's what I got:

[image]

And that is the result:

[image]

Why this proc shows (or returns?) me only 1 row? There must be more than one result, for sure (I've tried to write a simply **SELECT * FROM motherboards** statement, result is the same, only 1 row but my table has some about 50 rows). How could I get all results of this proc? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is only one match.

Comment: no, there are more than one, for sure, I've tried to write a simply SELECT * FROM motherboards statement, result is the same, only 1 row, but there are some about 50 rows in my table

Comment: the example you just gave suggests there is only one row in the table, why do you think there is more?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/h7EZH

Comment: and as I said before, I get only 1 row independently of a query (even select * gives me only 1 result)

Comment: @Burning I guess that it is similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36424445/5070879 . Ie. one of letter is `Cyrillic` but glyph is the same as latin.

Comment: Please try to copy one of values that does not match and paste here.

Comment: @lad2025 my motherboards.full_name is also varchar(50), so I believe, that the problem isn't in there

Comment: You mean full_name of what? MSI Z270 Tomahawk

Comment: Found out that the problem is connected with IN paramentr, without the parametr it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

When I've tried to call that procedure in php I got expected result, so, I believe that was just a bug in myPhpAdmin.

Comment: . . You should probably delete the question.