# SQL String are same but case equals method returns false

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL` to compare two columns and return `TRUE`/`FALSE` if they are equal.

In some cases, the two columns contain exactly the same string (no spaces or anything) but I am still getting false.

What may the reason for this be?

I am using this code:

```
CASE WHEN column1 = column2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [check]
```

Comment: convert both columns to lower case, and trim the whitespaces. You can also check the string length for both columns to see if there is any differences between them (maybe a whitespace).

Comment: You should compare the strings by pasting both of them to Notepad++ and enabling "Show invisible characters". They are not the same, they look the same

Comment: Another example they may use the same gliph but are  different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36424445/5070879

Answer (score 2):

The values are different despite the displayed value.

Using T-SQL, run a query like this to see the exact difference in the underlying raw values:

```
SELECT
     column1
    , CAST(column1 AS varbinary(MAX)) AS column1Binary
    , column2
    , CAST(column2 AS varbinary(MAX)) AS column2Binary
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

This will reveal underlying differences like tabs or subtle character differences.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, a likely explanation for what you are seeing is that one/both of the strings has leading and/or trailing whitespace.  On SQL Server you may try:

```
CASE WHEN LTRIM(column1) = LTRIM(column2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [check]
```

If the above does not detect the problematical records, then try checking the length:

```
CASE WHEN LEN(column1) = LEN(column2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [check2]
```

Comment: [SQL Server ignores trailing spaces when comparing `varchar` values, but not leading spaces.](https://rextester.com/OML35631)

Comment: Then maybe there are hidden characters which you can't see.  Check the `LEN` of both strings.  Or, there could be characters which look similar but are really not the same.

Comment: Note - tsql now has trim function to remove both leading and trailing spaces!