# What's the Differences between These Two Strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I'm baffling that I cannot find the differences between these two sets of strings, which look to be exactly the same for me. I checked for white space in between the strings, but no luck. When running below queries in SQL Management Studio, only one of them return results... Please help, thank you.

```
--return row
SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorCode = 'SRP  85072B'

--does not return row
SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorCode = 'SRP  85072B'

--return rows
SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorCode IN (
'ATT  60197S',
'GMI  98661A')

--does NOT RETURN rows
SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorCode IN (
'ATT  60197S',
'GMI  98661A')
```

Comment: They *are* identical. Or at least what you have posted (hopefully pasted). Take the time to give us a [mre].

Comment: Are you running them both from the same window under the same database?

Comment: Option 1: non-printable characters Option 2: [same glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355811/linq-query-not-behaving-as-expected/36424445#36424445) different code

Comment: @shawnt00 That is correct, same window, same database

Comment: @Larny They seem identical, but one returns row, the other does not

Comment: @Larnu looks like the markdown renderer renders non breaking spaces as regular spaces. The raw text is different

Comment: copy/paste 2 queries into an editor that can show hidden chars

Answer (score 6):

One of the strings has two consecutive regular spaces, the other has a non breaking space (character 160 decimal 0xA0 hex) followed by a regular space (character 32 decimal 0x20 hex).

You can see this from copying and pasting the strings [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63365684/edit/3e731fd2-9d75-48ef-8498-a6afa6bdcee9) as I have done here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0dc6ccc48439c3dc27a227aa2dffb4d2

```
0x4154542020363031393753    
0x415454A020363031393753
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your string or the column has special character CR or CRLF, try removing those characters in the comparison:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vendors 
WHERE replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim(VendorCode)), char(13), ''), char(10), '') = replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim('SRP  85072B')), char(13), ''), char(10), '')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry to say when I run it, it returns zero row...

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) to split apart the two strings, convert each character to its ascii value, and return the differences.

```
declare
  @string1      nvarchar(200)='zdq%E^&$DGE%^#((',
  @string2      nvarchar(200)='zdq%E^&$DGx%^#((';

select ascii(SUBSTRING(@string1, t.n, 1)), t.n from dbo.fnTally(1, len(@string1)) t
except
select ascii(SUBSTRING(@string2, t.n, 1)), t.n from dbo.fnTally(1, len(@string2)) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

They seem similar if you run the following sql query

```
DECLARE @first nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorCode = ''SRP  85072B''',
        @second nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorCode = ''SRP  85072B'''

IF (@first = @second)
    SELECT 'Similar';

ELSE
    SELECT 'Not Similar';
```

If the parameters are coming from the same source you may check using the following query

```
DECLARE @param nvarchar(max) = 'SRP  85072B'
SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorCode like  '%'+ @param+'%'
```