# TSQL: I have one basic querying problem qr

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Query:

```
DECLARE @Patd_base nvarchar(50) = '‪axx';

PRINT @Patd_base
```

Output is

```
?axx
```

Why is the `?` in the output? What does it mean?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why? show '?' in the query

Comment: Seems to be similiar to [Linq query not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36424445/5070879). The letter 'a' is not a Latin 'a' or you have some control characters. Using `DECLARE @Patd_base nvarchar(50) = N'‪axx';`  will not cause implicit conversion [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ec577b96ad74fc8a7a9ca4022e26738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you copied and pasted the value 'axx' from elsewhere. It has a hidden extended character in it.

When I copy/pasted your command above into Notepad++, and converted to ANSI encoding, I got `'â€ªaxx'`