# sql: string comparison

Tags: sql, string-comparison

I have the following `sql` code:

```
if ('aaa' = 'aAa') 
    print 'equals'
else
    print 'not equals'
```

And it prints `equals`. Why it's this behavior when the strings are not equals?

Comment: As per my knowledge, string comparison is not case sensitive in SQL.

Comment: You need to learn about string *collations*.  Obviously, the default for the database you are using is case-insensitive.

Comment: You might've forgot to add the `SQL Server` tag to this question, as it is `CASE INSENSITIVE` which might not be true with the others as like `PostgreSQL` or 'Oracle`

Comment: Related (sql-server): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity

Comment: There is no `IF` in "SQL" (the query language). Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use collations :

```
IF 'aaa' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'aAa' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
 print 'equals'
else
 print 'not equals'
```