# How to write a SQL query to print a,A if column values are a,A,A,A,a,A,a,A,a,a,a,A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in that I have only one column let say column name is XYZ and in that I have following values

```
a
a
A
a
A
A
a
```

I want a SQL query that should return me output as below:

```
a
A
```

Comment: select distinct XYZ order by XYZ

Comment: @DRapp Your query is correct only when collation is case sensitive. See Piotr answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use case sensitive collation.
Following query will show you how to define collation for distinct select

```
select distinct XYZ COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS from [your table]
```

The "CS" at the end of collation name defines that operations on this column should be case sensitive.

Comment: This query running perfect as i received expected output Thank u..
"select distinct XYZ COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS from letters"

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand why you get a single row if distinct used and why the case sensitive does not work.

> SQL Server is, by default, case insensitive; however, it is possible to create a case-sensitive SQL Server database and even to make specific table columns case sensitive. The way to determine if a database or database object is to check its "COLLATION" property and look for "CI" or "CS" in the result.

Source:- [https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-check-case-sensitivity-in-sql-server/#:~:text=SQL%20Server%20is%2C%20by%20default,%22CS%22%20in%20the%20result](https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-check-case-sensitivity-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=SQL%20Server%20is%2C%20by%20default,%22CS%22%20in%20the%20result).

Use collation for case sensitive enable or disable. There is different -2 type of level. ([SQL Server check case-sensitivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity), [How to do a case sensitive search in WHERE clause (I'm using SQL Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server))

[SQL Server check case-sensitivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity)

```
Declare @tableA table ( cola varchar(50))
insert into @tableA values ('a'),('A'),('b'),('B')

select distinct cola from @tableA

--here you get both
select * from @tableA where cola = 'a'

--here you get only what you passed
select cola  from @tableA where cola = 'a' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS --Latin1_General_CS_AI--COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

--here you get different result
select cola COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  from @tableA  where cola = 'a'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
select char(xyz) as xyz
from (select distinct ascii(xyz) as xyz from yourtable) a
```

If using ASCII character set.

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct(XYZ) from Letters
```

where `Letters` is the name of table.

Comment: Your query works only when collation is not case sesitive.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function and does not need brackets, they just confuse people into thinking it's only looking at that column. It operates over the whole resultset, not just the first column